# How to detect external microphone by Swift 5 in Simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a sound store app where I record sounds and store recorded sounds. Before recording the sound I wanna make sure the microphone is plugged in. How can I check if microphone is plugged in or not in Swift 5?

PS: I am using a simulator to test.

Comment: Check out this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-record-audio-using-avaudiorecorder) which shows how you can implement microphone pickup in Swift 5.

Comment: I have checked that one, It does not detect if microphone is present or not.

Comment: Isn't this accomplished by the attempt to call to `recordingSession.setActive(true)`?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "present"

Comment: If microphone is plugged in or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230743/discussion-between-the-swift-coder-and-tanvirgeek).

Answer (score 1):

By Using **AVAudioSession**

```
let port_Type = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.inputs
if(portDescription.portType == AVAudioSession.Port.headsetMic) {
   //do your work here
}
```

Refer to this Apple Documentation for more inputs and output ports  :-  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/port

Comment: This does not work in simulator. Can you please tell me how it can work in simulator?